# how to check how many table rows table had on validation failed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating rows of a table dynamically on button click event.Now For example,lets consider i have created total 7 rows dynamically now if i submit the form and there was some error in my form field so how would i come to know that how many total rows were created.

this is how i am creating rows dynamically

```
 counter=0;
 $('.add-row').click(function(){
    counter=counter+1;
    $("#custom_fields").append("<tr><td><input type=text name='slab_name[]'/><span class='help-inline'>"+slab_name+"</span></td><td><input type='text' name='slab_start[]'/><span class='help-inline'>"+slab_start+"</span></td><td><input type='text' name='slab_end[]'/><span class='help-inline'>"+slab_end+"</span></td><td><input type='text' name='monthly_recurring_cost[]'/><span class='help-inline'>"+mrc+"</span></td><td><input type='text' name='data_in_mbs_slabs[]'/><span class='help-inline'>"+dim+"</span></td><td><input type='text' name='no_of_sms_slabs[]'/><span class='help-inline'>"+nos+"</span></td></tr>");
    alert(counter);
});
```

here the counter is working but on page refresh obviously it would obviously show zero

Comment: Send the counter to the server with your page submit.

Comment: Why does how many rows were created affect the validation?

Comment: You can create one more hidden input, which will store info about rows and you can then send it with your form.

Comment: @DarrenSweeney each td of the table tr has input fields which require validation

Comment: @MuhammadTalha, please add more information as which server technology you are using and when do you want to count the number of rows previously created. More relevant information will attract more specific answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not wish to post the row counter to the server and get it on page refresh, you can use LocalStorage instead of a normal JavaScript variable, like below:

```
$('.add-row').click(function(){
   // do your stuff here.
   if (localStorage.counter) {
     localStorage.counter = Number(localStorage.counter) + 1;
   } else {
     localStorage.counter = 1;
   }
}
```

This will be stored in the localStorage even if you refresh your page. The `localStorage` and `sessionStorage` properties allow saving key/value pairs in a web browser. This value will also be available throughout your web browser. So you can even access it when you refresh your page.

Answer (score 0):

with jQuery?
simple:

```
$('#custom_fields tr').length
```

calculating "count" on refresh make no sence, unless you have it posted.

For server-side validation example:

```
    <?php 
       $count = $_POST['count'] ?: 0;
    ?>

    <form id="validator" method="POST"><input type='hidden' value=$count;>
    <button>validate</button>
    </form>
 <script>
 var count = <?=$count?>;
    // ... rest of your code ...
    // and additional JS:
    $('#validator').on('submit', () => {
       $('#validator input').val($('#custom_fields tr').length);
    })
</script>
```

Comment: That's a bit vague, what if there's more than one table on a page?

Comment: The problem OP might be facing while redisplaying the same page after form validation failure, so all dynamically created `tr`s are gone.

Comment: @VPK, validators can be client side ;)

Comment: @DarrenSweeney, totally agree, missed, that we actually have an ID in the post, tnx

Comment: `here the counter is working but on page refresh obviously it would obviously show zero` missing point?

Answer (score 0):

table contains tbody tag then use like this
`$('#tableId tbody tr').length;`

or else use like this 
`$('#tableId tr').length;`